# App cannot be installed in device after integrating firebase notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I have added these line to integrate firebase notification to my app

**build.gradle(module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.appname'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
   }
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.21.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle(project:appName)**

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
   }
 }

 allprojects {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
     }
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
       delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

If I try to run app after adding those dependencies then it shows the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task 
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcn$zza.class

Comment: Please post the entire set of dependencies from your `build.gradle` file, not just the `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'` line.

Comment: @CommonsWare updated question

Comment: Do you have anything in `libs/`? Also, you might want to run a Gradle dependency report to see if Facebook is pulling in any `com.google` artifacts that might duplicate ones that you are now getting from Firebase.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have no any 'libs/'

Comment: Then my best guess is a conflict between Firebase and the Facebook code. Since I use neither of these, I have no specific advice.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have used both of them in another app, but that was working fine. Issue is with this new app only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dependency report shows that `audience-network-sdk` has a transitive dependency on `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0`.  This is the source of the conflict.

I don't use the Facebook libs and am not sure of the best solution.  These two options will both allow you to build.  I don't know if each will support your code.  You'll have to experiment:

Option 1:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.21.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-ads'
})
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

Option 2:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.21.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
```

Comment: Both of the options worked fine. Thank you so much, you saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding packagingOptions in build.gradle after buildTypes

Code For packagingOptions

```
 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
```

Edited Code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.appname'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
   }
 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
   }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.21.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```